# Format read from file in Java

Tags: java, regex

I have got a file from which I should create instances of a class Model:

```
class Model{
      private a;
      private b;
      public Model1(double a, double b){
          this.a=a;
          this.b=b;                     
      }
}
```

The file look like this:

```
....
some lines
....
<Model>
a=1.564
b=57.789
<Model>
.....
<Model>
a=10.56
b=35.99
<Model>
.....
```

I don't know the number of "Models" in the file, so I will put it in a `list`
Here is my code

```
 public static void main(String... argc) throws FileNotFoundException{
    List<Model> list = new ArrayList<>();
    try(Scanner s = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("filePath"))))){
      // while(s.hasNextModel()){
         //     int a;
         //     int b;
         //     Here I should get a and b from the file
         //     list.add(new Model(a,b));
         //      }

    }
}
```

So, how should I read `a` and `b` from the file?

Comment: Your file looks like hacked XML; I don't think you'll find a nice library for reading that. You'll have to implement it yourself.

Comment: @Dave I have found `next(Pattern pattern)` method in `Scanner` class. Is it possible to use it here?

Answer (score 2):

Not using any xml libraries.

```
private class Model{
      private int a;
      private int b;
      //getters and setters
    }

    public List<Model> readModels(Scanner s){
        List<Model> list = new ArrayList<>();
        while(s.hasNextLine()){
              if(s.nextLine().equals("<Model>")){
                String valsA[] = s.nextLine().split("=");
                String valsB[] = s.nextLine().split("=");
                list.add(new Model(valsA[1],valsB[1]));
              }
        }
        return list;

     }
```

Comment: Very vulnerable to non-conforming files (and indentation), and the OP seems to be closing the model section with <model> too, but other than that this is probably the easiest way to do it.

Comment: Yes, this is only simple quick implementation but it is very dengerous  at all :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use json, or key/value, or serialised or XML format file for reading and writing the data.

This [Tutoial](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/) is one of easiest way to manipulating xml files.

Comment: …or json, or key/value, or serialised, or custom formats, or etc.